# how to make an xml file open cv readable?

Tags: python, xml, image-processing, opencv

i have an xml file which is haar cascade and supposed to be on server , but I wanna use it in my openCV file code , how should I do that? btw I used <opencv_storage> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full paths of the xml. The xml files are located under the

> opencv\data\haarcascades

location.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```